# Android learning curve

Tags: android

I have experience in Java and good understanding of OOP. 2-3 weeks ago I decided to learn to make applications for Android. 
      The problem is that all the books I have gotten through aren't looking to me extensive enough. Most of the books are about 300-400 pages long and can't properly cover decent amount of aspects needed to understand all the fundamentals. I'm currently reading "pro Andorid 4" by Reto Meier and it's one of the most detailed resources on the Internet but still not enough.
   I find the Android framework pretty complex. There are Activities, Intents, Services and other APIs. The Android dev guide on the official page is really brief and can't make a detailed coverage of the main components. And I find other resources not detailed enough, too. The usage and the properties of Intents aren't explaind well enough especially for the implicit ones with the Intent constants and the Uri object as a second parameter in the Intens constructor, etc. Also I can't find information for other aspects and usage for Context, Cursor and what some actions return after the execution of onActivityResult() method and so on.
For this periond I gained knowledge for some basic and trivial stuff, but I'm very confused when I have to implement some not so common features like taking pictures, using broadcast recievers and services

So my question is - Where can I find more comprehensive and in depth explanations of Android's inner components?
And also how much time did it take for you to fluently make Android applications and fully understand everything involved into the development?

Comment: "Most of the books are about 300-400 pages long" -- FWIW, [mine is over 1700 pages long](http://commonsware.com/). And my pages are bigger, too. :-)  Beyond that, if you are looking for some single magical Source of All Android Knowledge, you will likely be disappointed. We have over 200,000 questions here on StackOverflow, covering a vast number of use cases and scenarios, which can be used to supplement the official docs, whatever book(s) you get, etc.

Comment: If can't find the information you want in books, blogs or StackOverflow... there is always the [Android Source Code](http://source.android.com/)

Comment: The time where you can fully understand an entire platform is long, long gone. Start by writing prototypes and ask yourself detailed questions on how you can improve.

Comment: Looks like a nice book. I might check it after I finish my current one. But I want to ask how did you personally learned all this? And where do you make references?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Where can I find more comprehensive and in depth explanations of
>   Android's inner components?

The official Android documentation is very good. http://developer.android.com/guide/components/index.html

> And also how much time did it take for you to fluently make Android
>   applications...

Depends on what do you understand by "fluently". Let's say that without copying Hello World, looking what was the Activity all about etc. about 2 weeks.

> ...and fully understand everything involved into the development?

There is no need to *fully* understand *everything* now. Don't worry. Later you will understand most of the useful concepts. At the beggining just try to make some app and use Google all the time. Most of the time you know more or less how to do 90% and you just read up these lasting 10% of which you have no idea yet.

Comment: Thumbs up for "There is no need to fully understand everything now"